# import a html page to a google sheet with app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an HTML file that gets emailed to a Gmail account every day as an attachment. I then get the attachment and save it to a google drive without problems.

What I need to do is get that HTML file into a google sheet. Now I can do a manual import and upload the HTML file and it works 100%, but I need to do this automatically within my script.

IMPORTHTML will not work as I need to get the whole file into the sheet. I can't seem to find any way to do this with code.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like this:

```
GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[i].getMessages()[j].getAttachments()[k].getDataAsString();
```

Put the string right into a cell in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Let me give it a try, Thank you